Apache Superset Google BigQuery extended image error
I want to install Google Big Query Database Driver into my Superset configuration.
I use official documentation
I tried using this tip but it did not work.
Steps I do:
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset
cd superset

Then I created requirements-local.txt in docker sub-directory with such contents
sqlalchemy-bigquery

Then I want to rebuild image
docker compose build --force-rm

I receive such error
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run ${BUILD_CMD}" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

